# Applications of the axiom of choice to non-existence proofs

Tags: soft-question, axiom-of-choice

I've been thinking about Monsky's Theorem that it is impossible to partition a square into an odd number of triangles of equal area. The [proof](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317329?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A30090968a6378f9337b6a3df0316e831&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) depends on a theorem of Chevalley to extend the $2$-adic valaution on $\mathbb{Q}$ to a $2$-adic valuation on $\mathbb{R}$, and Chevalley's theorem relies on the axiom of choice for its proof.  According to "Proofs from THE BOOK" (fifth edition, p.$151$) no other proof of Monsky's theorem is known.

If Monsky's theorem were false, the counterexample would be a finite, easily comprehensible object.  All the other applications of the axiom of choice I can think of assert the existence of some infinite, complicated object that we don't expect to be able to construct: a Hamel basis for the reals over the rationals, a free ultrafilter, a bounded, non-measurable subset of the reals, and so on.

I recognize that Chevalley's theorem itself asserts the existence of just such an object, but I haven't been able to think of another example where the axiom or one of its consequences is used to prove the non-existence of some "concrete" finite object.  I exclude the extensions of Monsky's theorem to other polygons and higher dimensions, of course.

Are such examples really rare?  Can you supply any more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is a precise result which says that the axiom of choice **cannot** be necessary for too-concrete results (and in particular that it's not necessary to Monsky's theorem). This is **Shoenfield absoluteness**:

> Suppose $P$ is a $\Pi^1_2$ theorem of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Then $P$ is already provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Actually Shoenfield says even more - e.g. [CH](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuum-hypothesis/) won't be necessary either - but the above is already enough for the OP. It's also worth noting that Shoenfield is in fact **completely constructive**: it gives a very concrete way to transform a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof into a $\mathsf{ZF}$-proof.

"$\Pi^1_2$" is a purely *syntactic* notion: roughly speaking, a sentence is $\Pi^1_2$ if it has the form "For all $X$ there is some $Y$ such that $H(X,Y)$," where $X$ and $Y$ are "morally equivalent" to real numbers and $H$ involves only quantification over things "morally equivalent" to natural numbers. For example, finitely sets of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and continuous functions $\mathbb{R}^a\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^b$ are "morally equivalent" to real numbers, while rational numbers are "morally equivalent" to nautral numbers. Monsky's theorem falls into this category: a triangulation is specified by a finite tuple of reals, and the equal-area property amounts to saying that we can get approximations to the relevant areas which are within arbitrary positive rational differences from each other. *(In fact this only involved one "interesting" quantification, namely over finite tuples of reals, so in fact Monsky's theorem is $\Pi^1_1$.)*

---

Note that the above **may not** truly constitute an error in *PftB*: Shoenfield merely transforms an existing proof into a sharper proof, and one could still claim that we have no proof of Monsky's theorem whose *idea* doesn't use Choice. But on a purely technical level, choice cannot be necessary for the proof of such a concrete result.

Comment: Thank you.  This is way beyond my knowledge of set theory and logic.  "There exists a proof of Monsky's theorem that does not rely on the axiom of choice."  Amazing that such a statement can be proved.

Comment: @saulspatz Here's roughly how the proof goes, FYI. The trick is to use [Godel's constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe). Essentially, every model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZF}$ has a "definable region" $L^M$ within which Choice holds. Via this construction $M\mapsto L^M$ we can turn *correctness* results into *translation* results: if we know "Regardless of what $M$ is, $L^M$ and $M$ agree on whether $P$ is true" then we know "If $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves $P$ then $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves $P$" (since if $M\models\mathsf{ZF}+P$ then we would have $L^M\models\mathsf{ZFC}+P$).

Comment: (Below I'll suppress $M$.) So we just need to show "$L$ is correct for $\Pi^1_2$ sentences." This is a nontrivial argument, but the first piece - $\Pi^1_1$ absoluteness, which is enough for Monsky - is not too hard to describe. The first point is that every $\Pi^1_1$ statement is equivalent to the *well-foundedness* of a certain tree; basically, think of a tree whose nodes describe approximations to counterexamples of the $\Pi^1_1$ statement, and so whose paths would give actual counterexamples. Now $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that such a tree either has a path or has a ranking function.

Comment: That's an **existential** statement, and the property of being a path or being a ranking function is simple enough that it's absolute between any two transitive models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. So the relevant tree looks well-founded in $L$ iff it actually is well-founded. *(Bootstrapping this to $\Pi^1_2$ then requires a clever trick, and genuinely pushes us into set theory proper: we need to construe a $\Pi^1_2$ statement as a well-foundedness statement as well, but now the relevant trees are much more complicated.)*

Comment: (A bit of terminology: $\Pi^1_1$ absoluteness, which as I said above is sufficient for Monsky, is **Mostowski absoluteness**.) And the above also tells us how to whip up a choice-free proof of Monsky: $(1)$ Rephrase the usual $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of Monsky as a $\mathsf{ZF}$-proof of "Monsky is true in $L$." $(2)$ Prove Shoenfield absoluteness if you haven't already. $(3)$ Combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get Monsky. So Shoenfield is awesome but the choice-free proof we get is rather silly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain all this, but it will take me some thinking to wrap my head around it (if indeed I can).  Is there someplace on the Web I can read more about this?

Comment: @saulspatz Chapter $4$ of [Kunen's old book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/set-theory-an-introduction-to-independence-proofs/kunen/978-0-444-86839-8) develops the basic ideas of absoluteness, in the context of analyzing the axiom of Foundation/Regularity (which isn't relevant to us, admittedly). With this understood you'll be prepped for the more difficult material needed for Mostowski (put off Shoenfield until later): the first step after all is to show that well-foundedness of appropriate trees is absolute between models of $\mathsf{ZF}$. With that in hand, you now have two remaining tasks:

Comment: understand the construction and basic analysis of $L$ (which is quite involved), and connect $\Pi^1_1$ sentences and well-foundedness claims (which is quite easy but unmotivated without the absoluteness fact above - or a preexisting interest in computability theory or descriptive set theory).